# Unit test in a C function with a static variable

Tags: c, unit-testing, static

Let the following C function

```
void underTest(){
  static int i = 0;
  i++;
  if (i > 50*1000*1000) {
    /* I want to test this */
  }
}
```

I need to unit-test this function, including the if block. Among solutions I can foresee, there is:

- Do whatever it takes to reach all cases using the expected interface (including calling the function a lot of times in that example), which may be a real hassle
- Reading the memory map after test compilation to access `i` from its memory address

  - either modifying the object code
  - or changing the source and hoping the recompilation will be deterministic
- Forget testing and use peer review instead, which is no good solution either given the cost

**Note**: because this is code to be embedded in an aircraft, with very high requirements on test representativity, any form of code modification (including a `#define static extern` trick) is unacceptable. Also, modifying the code to remove the issue (e.g. making `i` global) would cost an arm.

Does somebody know a trick out of this annoying situation? No matter how dirty it is, as long as source code is untouched.

Comment: Tell me what the company/model of the aircraft to avoid using it (because of such crap code and tricks with unit tests)

Comment: *"modifying the code to remove the issue (e.g. making i global) would cost an arm"* Better than an arm **and** a leg, I suppose.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: Old versions of Airbus 300 have no software at all. For newer ones, you'll have to deal with tricks: the problem is not how dirty tricks are, but whether they imply a risk on passenger safety. And to clarify: the code I posted is just an example, there are many good reasons for not posting aircraft real code on stackoverflow, let alone telling you where they run :)

Comment: @PPC *the problem is not how dirty tricks are, but whether they imply a risk on passenger safety* - and who is deciding? If the person deciding thinks UB is fine as long as it is passing a "unit test", then I am worried (there is no UB here, just speaking hypothetically).

Comment: You could run `gdb` under script control and use it to set the value of `i` before calling `under_test`. There are many other tricks [that I've used]. (e.g. You can copy the real.c to test.c and change `static` [to global] there.)

Comment: Can you recompile the FUT (function under test) so that instead of 50 million cycles, it goes into the code after 50 cycles?  Either by changing the limit value from 50 million to 50, or by changing the increment from 1 to 1 million?  Frankly, though, if you want to make the design testable, you need to expose that static variable so it is outside the function, not inside it, so that it can be manipulated appropriately for testing.  What you've got is not readily testable.  And the fact that the code can't be reached for 50 million cycles means that the developers have not tested it either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: both changes you propose are unacceptable since every bit of the source code must be frozen before test. The regular way to deal with that is to declare the function untestable and send it back to the developer, but that would delay the aircraft delivery for a year. And having developers test their code... Man, don't ever set a foot in aircraft software!

Comment: @EugeneSh. : Some highly skilled specialists take this kind of decision, based on data fed back by software stakeholders. And by some I mean many. If you're interested, they usually apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP4761

Comment: @EugeneSh. What is UB by the way? University of Barcelona/Burgundy?

Comment: @PPC: in a context where C is discussed, UB usually means 'undefined behaviour'.

Comment: If you can't change the code to test it, send it back to the developers as untestable and therefore unacceptable.  They have to make sure their code meets the requirements for testability as well as functionality.  Since you can't make changes, they will have to.  Futzing with the object code should be less acceptable than modifying the source code — you can keep records of changes made to source code in CM systems; you have to work harder to manage records keeping if you're hacking the object code.  (Yes, I'm sure there are corporate politics involved.  Your job is to test testable code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *modifying object code* you mean modifying the generated .elf, that will not work since `i` is allocated by the loader at *launch-time*... (surely I misunderstood it, just wanted to clarify it).

You will need to find out the address of the `i` variable in the .bss section once loaded and access it directly. You do not say which compiler you are using, but, for example, AFAIK gcc has extensions to specify the address of a variable/symbol at source code level and at linking time, yours?

Another solution is to place the .bss at known address throuhg linker script.

Comment: I keep the idea of using a custom linker script, or perhaps a pragma to fix the address of `i` instead of blindly relying on a deterministic linker. For information, I am cross-compiling with nothing as fancy as gcc, and my question addresses several projects and targets. Usually microcontrollers or chips like MPC555

Answer (score -1):

Refactor you code to be testable.
Transform

```
void underTest(){
  static int i = 0;
  i++;
  if (i > 50*1000*1000) {
    /* I want to test this */
  }
}
```

to

```
void alsoUnderTest(){
    /* I want to test this */
}

void underTest(){
  static int i = 0;
  i++;
  if (i > 50*1000*1000) {
    alsoUnderTest()
  }
}
```

Comment: Not acceptable in my context. Changing a whitespace in source code litterally cost tens of thousands at the very least.